# Display value from select list using javascript

Tags: javascript

how can I display option value from the select list in my consol.log without selecting it twice. Now it works but I need to click twice to diplay it.

**JS**

```
function formatClick() {
    screenName = document.getElementById("linkscreen").value;
    console.log(screenName);
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/edinpuzic/ccogfkxn/8/)

Comment: You mean `onchange` vs `onclick`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this context, `click` event seems inappropriate. Use `change` event instead.

```
  .. .. onchange="formatClick()">
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ccogfkxn/9/)

And additionally, I would advise you to not to use an inline event handler. Use a dedicated event handler like below,

```
document.getElementById("linkscreen").addEventListener("change", formatClick, false);
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ccogfkxn/10/)